# Pythont 3.6.5 SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have just started writing in python, and the indentation is taking the best of me.
I have this code:

```
import json

if __name__ == '__main__':
    is_json('test')

def is_json(str):
    try:
        json.loads(str)
    except ValueError, e:
        return False
    return True
```

Which throws:

> File "so.py", line 9
>       except ValueError, e:
>                        ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I am using only tabs.

Comment: it's not an indentation issue, but a syntax one (as the error message actually says). Replace `,` with `as` and you should be fine, i.e. `except ValueError as e`

Comment: That's not an indentation error. You used the Python 2 syntax for `except` in Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code had two mistakes:

- First in the `except` part
- Second is that you declared `is_json` at the bottom

If you declare at bottom you may get `NameError: name 'is_json' is not defined` error.

```
    import json

    def is_json(str):
        try:
            json.loads(str)
        except ValueError as e:
            return False
        return True

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        is_json('test')
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the below 2 points.

(1) Python3 uses different syntax for **try-except** statement for exception handling.

> **Replace** `except ValueError, e:` with `except ValueError as e:`.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

(2) **Define** your function before if statement. Function definition should be available before the point of usage (call).

```
import json

def is_json(str):
    try:
        json.loads(str)
    except ValueError as e:
        return False
    return True 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(is_json('test')); # False
```

Thanks.